# PostgreSQL - view with concatenated columns using the column's index

Tags: sql, database, postgresql

Is it possible to make use of index when indexed columns are being concatenated in a non-materialized view?

For example:

```
create table data (
    id int,
    col_1 varchar,
    col_2 varchar,
    status varchar(10),
    primary key (id)
);

create index idx_data_col_1_col2 on data (col_1, col_2);

create view vw_data as
   select (col_1 || '-' || col_2) as key,      
          status
   from data;

insert into data values (1,'Mick', 'Mari', 'ok');
insert into data values (2,'Rick', 'Dan',  'ok');
insert into data values (3,'John', 'Ana',  'ok');

-- I want it being scan by index
select * from vw_data where key = 'Mick-Ana';
```

Is there any way to make it work?

**UPDATE**

As suggested below, I created an index but didn't make any difference on the way data is being scanned

```
-- using the table. 
explain analyze select * from data where col_1 = 'Mick' and col_2 = 'Mari';
--Index Scan using idx_data_col_1_col2 on data  (cost=0.15..2.37 rows=1 width=106) (actual time=0.015..0.016 rows=1 loops=1)
--  Index Cond: (((col_1)::text = 'Mick'::text) AND ((col_2)::text = 'Mari'::text))
--Planning Time: 0.085 ms
--Execution Time: 0.044 ms

-- using the view on the concatenated key column before creating the index
explain analyze select * from vw_data where key = 'Mick-Mari';
--Seq Scan on data  (cost=0.00..20.52 rows=3 width=70) (actual time=0.015..0.017 rows=1 loops=1)
--  Filter: ((((col_1)::text || '-'::text) || (col_2)::text) = 'Mick-Mari'::text)
--  Rows Removed by Filter: 2
--Planning Time: 0.104 ms
--Execution Time: 0.057 ms

-- create the index
create index idx_data_key
    ON data ((col_1 || '-' || col_2));

-- using the view on the concatenated key column after creating the index
explain analyze select * from vw_data where key = 'Mick-Mari';
--Seq Scan on data  (cost=0.00..1.06 rows=1 width=70) (actual time=0.014..0.016 rows=1 loops=1)
--  Filter: ((((col_1)::text || '-'::text) || (col_2)::text) = 'Mick-Mari'::text)
--  Rows Removed by Filter: 2
--Planning Time: 2.780 ms
--Execution Time: 0.056 ms
```

**UPDATE 2**

The approach above didn't work because the amount of data was too small and using an index would be slower. In a bigger amount of data I can see the index being used.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a matrialized view

```
create table data (
    id int,
    col_1 varchar,
    col_2 varchar,
    status varchar(10),
    primary key (id)
);
```

> ```
> CREATE TABLE
> ```

```
CREATE MATERIALIZED VIEW vw_data as
   select (col_1 || '-' || col_2) as key,      
          status
   from data;;

CREATE UNIQUE INDEX idx_vw_dat
  ON vw_data (key, status);
```

> ```
> SELECT 0
> ```

> ```
> CREATE INDEX
> ```

```
insert into data values (1,'Mick', 'Mari', 'ok');
insert into data values (2,'Rick', 'Dan',  'ok');
insert into data values (3,'John', 'Ana',  'ok');
```

```
select * from vw_data where key = 'Mick-Ana';
```

| key | status |
| --- | --- |

> ```
> SELECT 0
> ```

```
EXPLAIN select * from vw_data where key = 'Mick-Ana';
```

| QUERY PLAN |
| --- |
| Bitmap Heap Scan on vw_data (cost=4.18..12.64 rows=4 width=70) |
| Recheck Cond: (key = 'Mick-Ana'::text) |
| -> Bitmap Index Scan on idx_vw_dat (cost=0.00..4.18 rows=4 width=0) |
| Index Cond: (key = 'Mick-Ana'::text) |

> ```
> EXPLAIN
> ```

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/35WkEtxk)

As you can't make an index on a view, you can do it as generated column

```
create table data (
    id int,
    col_1 varchar,
    col_2 varchar,
    status varchar(10)
  ,
    new_key varchar(100) GENERATED ALWAYS AS (col_1 || '-' || col_2) STORED,
  
    primary key (id)
);
```

> ```
> CREATE TABLE
> ```

```
CREATE VIEW vw_data as
   select new_key as key,      
          status
   from data;;

CREATE UNIQUE INDEX idx_dat
  ON data (new_key, status);
```

> ```
> CREATE VIEW
> ```

> ```
> CREATE INDEX
> ```

```
insert into data values (1,'Mick', 'Mari', 'ok');
insert into data values (2,'Rick', 'Dan',  'ok');
insert into data values (3,'John', 'Ana',  'ok');
```

```
select * from vw_data where key = 'Mick-Ana';
```

| key | status |
| --- | --- |

> ```
> SELECT 0
> ```

```
EXPLAIN select * from vw_data where key = 'Mick-Ana';
```

| QUERY PLAN |
| --- |
| Index Only Scan using idx_dat on data (cost=0.14..8.16 rows=1 width=256) |
| Index Cond: (new_key = 'Mick-Ana'::text) |

> ```
> EXPLAIN
> ```

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/MZBiKTsb)

Comment: If I haven´t said "in a non-materialized view" in the first line of my question, it would be the solution :)

Comment: postgres only can make indexes on tables and materialzed views, so if you don't want a mertilized view you cab use a genarated column and use that as basis for an index